# GNS3 install fails on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

Tags: 22.04, repository, add-apt-repository

I am trying to install GNS3 by adding PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gns3/ppa
```

Getting following error:

```
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/__init__.py:87: RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (2.0.7) or chardet (4.0.0) doesn't match a supported version!
  warnings.warn("urllib3 ({}) or chardet ({}) doesn't match a supported "
OS codename: 'jammy'.
This codename isn't currently supported.
Please check your OS release information with "cat /etc/os-release" (identified as VERSION_CODENAME).
```